# How can I have a list of base class objects and access derived class fields?

Tags: c++, list, c++17, std

Let's say I have a base class and two derived classes:

```cpp
class a {};
class b : a { int a; };
class c : a { int b; };
```

And I have a list of the base class, and I insert the derived class into the list:

```cpp
std::list<a> list;

list.emplace_back(b());
list.emplace_back(c());
```

Now, I want to access `int a` like this:

```cpp
for(auto i : list)
{
    i.a = 5;
}
```

I already have checks in place to see what class it is, but the compiler is still not letting me access it.

How can I access any field in the derived class from the base class?

This question has been asked many times, but none of the methods have worked for me so far.

Comment: `std::list<a>` will perform [Object Slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing). There is no derived fields to access. First you need a `std::list<std::unique_ptr<A>>` or similar, from there this question may have an answer.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux ok i did that and now i'm getting
function "std::unique_ptr<..etc" cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function

Comment: Consider changing your design - if you want to use a container of base class pointers, you should also have virtual functions rather than accessing fields of derived classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need a list of base class *pointers*, otherwise you will [slice the objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/) when you insert them into the list.

Then, you need to type-cast the pointers to access derived classes as needed.

If all of the list elements are pointing at the same derived type, you can use `static_cast`:

```cpp
struct A {};
struct B : A { int a; };
struct C : A { int b; };

std::list<std::unique_ptr<A>> lst;

lst.push_back(std::make_unique<B>());
lst.push_back(std::make_unique<B>());

for(auto &ptr : lst)
{
    static_cast<B*>(ptr.get())->a = 5;
}
```

Otherwise, use `dynamic_cast` instead to test the derived class type before accessing its fields:

```cpp
struct A {};
struct B : A { int a; };
struct C : A { int b; };

std::list<std::unique_ptr<A>> lst;

lst.push_back(std::make_unique<B>());
lst.push_back(std::make_unique<C>());

for(auto &ptr : lst)
{
    B *b = dynamic_cast<B*>(ptr.get());
    if (b)
        b->a = 5;
}
```

Comment: Disclaimer: the author if this post will not held responsible for damages caused by paying the cost of runtime polymorphism without any apparent advantage

Comment: really appreciate this, i'm surprised that of all the people that have asked this question no one has given this answer

Comment: @MatG Granted, polymorphism should be used to abstract away details like this, but there are also valid use-cases for wanting to access specific fields, too. We are here to share knowledge and answer questions on how to do specific things. And sure, suggest better choices, too.

Comment: @MaxCE there are plenty of questions on SO that have answers demonstrating the use of polymorphism with typecasting pointers to access derived classes. It is just that when using polymorphism the way it is intended, you shouldn't *need* to do that in the first place.

Comment: @RemyLebeau That was a little joke, you strictly answered the question

Comment: @MaxCE To show your appreciation you should also upvote the answer, I'll do that for you

Comment: @matG i can't i need to have 15 reputation

Comment: @MaxCE That's the reason I did that for you